# Can the Tree Stride spell be used on a transformed Staff of the Woodlands?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

The transformation ability of the [Staff of the Woodlands](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/staff-of-the-woodlands) says:

> ***Tree Form.*** You can use an action to plant one end of the staff in fertile earth and expend 1 charge to transform the staff into a healthy tree. The tree is 60 feet tall and has a 5-foot-diameter trunk, and its branches at the top spread out in a 20-foot radius. The tree appears ordinary but radiates a faint aura of transmutation magic if targeted by *detect magic*. While touching the tree and using another action to speak its command word, you return the staff to its normal form. Any creature in the tree falls when it reverts to a staff.

The relevant part of the [*tree stride*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tree-stride) spell says:

> You gain the ability to enter a tree and move from inside it to inside another tree of the same kind within 500 feet.

If I transform a Staff of the Woodlands into a tree, can I use the *tree stride* spell with it?

If so, how would I determine what type of tree it is for the spell?  Is it random?  Would it only be able to teleport between other transformed Staff of the Woodlands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes, but the type of tree the staff transforms into is up to the DM

**Tree Stride** (PHB p. 283) will allow you to travel between trees as long as they are trees "of the same kind".

However, the **Staff of the Woodlands** (DMG p. 204) does not actually say *what type of tree* it transforms into, other than it is a "healthy" tree and it gives its dimensions.

**I would say that you need to ask the DM what type of tree appears?**

For example, the tree is an Oak, then you could potentially use Tree Stride if there is another oak in the vicinity, or withing 500 feet to be precise.

There are other questions which would require a DM's ruling, such as "Does the *Staff of the Woodlands* always create the same type of tree?

If I was running the campaign, as a Rule as Cool, I would allow the tree to take the shape of trees that are commonly found in the area in which the party is currently adventuring. I might even -if I was feeling generous- allow the user of the staff to choose the type of tree. But, this might not suit all settings or DMs so it's important to bear that in mind.

Happy tree hopping!

Answer (score 1):

### Yes; if you have at least 2 staffs

The staff is a healthy tree. You can stride to another tree “of the same kind” i.e. another Staff of the Woodlands kind.

Comment: Can you support the claim that the *staff of the woodlands* transforms into a unique kind of tree (since you're saying that if *tree stride* is used on it, it can only be used to move into another transformed *staff of the woodlands*)?